# ZK 7 Selectors.iterable is not working for attribute with empty value

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, zk

I create my components in ZK with the WidgetAttribute "attribute" and any value with `comp.setWidgetAttribute("attribute", anyValue)`.

When I define the selector "[attribute]", without a value (like CSS3), in ZK, I use `Selectors.iterable(comp, selector)`, it throws an exception. It can't parse the selector, but using jQuery CSS3 selectors, jQuery returns a list of DOM elements contains this selector.

If I try this selector "[attribute=""]", the parse is sucessful, but, it search for `comp.getAttribute(selector)` when its value is empty.

How can I search in my page a list of Components with WidgetAttribute without value in ZK?
Can I override this method?

`static boolean ComponentLocalProperties.matchAttributes(Component component, List attributes)`